# The package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel is accessible from more than one module: poi, poi.ooxm

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

in above all reference for this question it is **not** solved and dont give maven because **not** doing in **maven.**
error is [image: error can be seen image]The package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel is accessible from more than one module: poi, poi.ooxm 
in both error

**i have to use both poi and poi--ooxml, please run this code i need to use it. even this code is sopied from the internet itself and there are many blogs who are showing this type code and it is the actual my requirement but its not working.**

Comment: Don't use modules! Just put them on the classpath, not the module path

Comment: [Apache POI does not yet fully support the Java 9 module system...as Apache POI currently uses the same package in different jar-files](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N102B0). But this is only the reason. I've also not a solution. At least not using Eclipse since I am not using that IDE. The next `apache poi` version `4.0` seems to avoid "using the same package in different jar-files".

Comment: Then how can use it. As they both are compulsorily required for this program. Solution?

Comment: Switching from poi-ooxml - 3.17 to poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

If someone have same issue just download new version of POI, old one is not compatible with new versions of java

Comment: Upgrading to 4.1.2 from 3.11 fixed the issue for me. I was having trouble even if I had excluded poi from poi-ooxml in pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and figured out the solution. it's a little late but may help someone else facing the same problem.
in your module remove "requires poi" and just keep requires poi.ooxml;

```
module com.example.MyModlue {
  //other require statement goes here
   requires poi.ooxml;
}
```

now in your code

in place of using (CellType.NUMERIC)
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;

for getting the cell type use (cell.getCellTypeEnum().NUMERIC) where cell if of type XSSFCell

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I'm using the `var` type inference to avoid referencing the types directly.

Answer (score 0):

just in module class add all lib in requires

```
module MyProjct {
    requires poi;
    requires poi.excelant;
    requires poi.ooxml;
    requires poi.ooxml.schemas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to multiple jars versions present in your eclipse setup.
Try deleting old/new versions depending on your requirement and try it will work.